# Masking range of bits in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm trying to write a method in C that accepts three integers: start, end, and mask. If mask is 1, all bits except the bits in the range of start to end are set to 0, and the bits in the range are set to 1. I have this part working at the moment:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (end - start + 1); i++)
{
  if (mask == 1)
  {
    ret |= ret << 1;
    ret |= ret | 1;
  }
}...ret = ret << start;
```

(where 'ret' is an unsigned int and simply starts as 0 if mask is 1 or ~0 if mask is 0). However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do it the other way: masking a range of bits as 0 and setting all of the rest to 1.

Comment: You turn _off_ bits with an "and" operator (`&` or `&=` for assignment version).  You use a mask consisting of the bits you want to leave _on_. (0 for bits you want to turn off.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since flipping the mask from 1 to 0 simply inverts the result, you can ignore the mask, build the return for `mask == 1`, and flip its bits at the end if the mask is zero:

```
int ret = 0;
for (int i = start ; i <= end ; i++) {
    ret |= 1 << i;
}
if (!mask) {
    ret = ~ret;
}
```

Comment: Ha, that was a lot simpler than I thought. Although, calling getMask(0, 0, 0) seems to be a special case, as it's returning 0, when the first (0th) bit should be the only one set to 0. Is there something wrong with my original masking method? Actually, calling the method with the starting bit as 0 always returns 0, regardless of what I make the ending bit. I've removed the 'if' statement as well.

Comment: @JohnProctor There's nothing wrong with your approach, although loop body is equivalent to `ret <<= 1; ret |= 1;` or even `ret = (ret << 1) | 1;` It could be sped up using [one of bit hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html), but the readability would suffer a lot.

Comment: Ha nevermind, forgot to remove the part where I set ret = ~0 if mask is 0. Thanks for the help